# How do I combine my two accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I made a mistake and now I have two mathoverflow accounts. I have an account on stackExchange and another account on Yahoo. How do I combine these two accounts? Is there any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a page on that on the "contact us" page at https://meta.mathoverflow.net/contact/user-merge

Just follow the instructions there, and you should be able to merge your accounts.