# What happened to my previous posts?

Tags: support, user-accounts, login

Recently, I logged-in to mathoverflow (after a period of inactivity) to find out that none of my previous posts shows up. Can anyone shed a light on this?

Comment: Please fill out the form at http://mathoverflow.net/contact

Answer (score 5):

It seems there are two users called passerby51, one who has been a memeber for 53 days, the other has been a memeber for 2.5 years, and has 6 questions and an answer.  If both of these are you, request that the two accounts be merged.

see [How do I combine my two accounts?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/432/how-do-i-combine-my-two-accounts/433)

Comment: Thanks. It seems so, although I cannot see the other account. Who/how should I ask this?

Comment: The problem with the solution in that link is that I cannot see the other account. I have only used my Goolge account to enter this site and that redirects to the newer account here. Do you see which email address is associated with that account?

Comment: I see the public profile for the older account here: http://mathoverflow.net/users/13049/passerby51, but I don't have access to it.

Comment: @passerby51 this a particular problem with Google after the softwareupgrade many had it see http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/15/how-can-i-log-in-into-my-old-mathoverflow-account for details. The basic solution is still the same; using the contact form. This is just to reassure you that it is not a problem you do not have access as this happened to many (including me) and is a known issue int this particular context;

Comment: @quid, OK, thanks, I sent the request.