# Can someone please help me login to my account

Tags: support, user-accounts, login

I'm so sorry, but I got logged out of my account:
https://mathoverflow.net/users/10290/erin-carmody

I tried to log back in but have changed my email several times... It might be an impossible task.  It really is me.  Erin Carmody from CUNY

Comment: I have some comments and future questions which might be very important to the future of mathematics, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can try to request the merging the accounts yourself [using the standard tool](https://mathoverflow.net/help/merging-accounts). Maybe this will not work but still worth trying. It seems that users who were in similar situation in the past got similar advice: [How do I combine my two accounts?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/432).

Comment: Erin: there's a 'Contact' button squirreled away at the bottom of this page (scroll down to the gray area, and look under MathOverflow Meta at the far left). Hit that button; under the menu you will see an option for an account merger request, and take it from there. Experience shows you may have to wait a few days for the merger; report back here if you haven't had success in about 3 days time.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: What has happened here? -- The account merger hasn't taken place, but rather Erin's original account appears to have been deleted(?)

Comment: @StefanKohl She says she deleted an account here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333967/are-either-pi-e-or-pi-e-transcendental-if-we-add-or-multiply-digit-wise. The thing is, site moderators are not able to merge accounts, so our ability to help is slightly limited although we can perhaps escalate attention to Community Management if she wants. And without an ID number, it's hard to track down the history of an account. So I'm afraid I can't answer your question.